# Как поставить пробел после вывода текста вместе с переменной?

Tags: c++

```
cout<<"The next number for the number"<<a<<"is"<<b<<"."<<endl;
   cout<<"The previos number for the number"<<a<<"is"<<c<<".";
```

Собственно вот сам код. Нужно поставить пробелы перед выводом переменных. То есть: "следующее число... и тут сразу выскакивает переменная, необходим пробел.

Comment: `...number"` заменить на `...number "`?

Comment: Ну просто допишите его в конце строки!...

Answer (score 1):

```
cout<<"The next number for the number  "<<a<<"is "<<b<<"."<<endl;
   cout<<"The previos number for the number  "<<a<<"is "<<c<<".";
```